# How Elixir Supervisor stops children on stop?

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

I have a supervisor with `:simple_one_to_one` restart strategy, what happens with children when I call `Supervisor.stop(sup)`?

From the tests I see that they're dying no matter what they were doing. Is there standard way to shut them down gracefully, so that they could finish the job (if any)? Something like calling `GenServer.stop` on them...

Answer (score 1):

Ivan. I think you want to trap exits on your workers. If you do not trap them they simply get killed. Here is an illustration of what I mean:

```
defmodule SupervisorStop do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [ worker(SupervisorStop.Worker, []) ]

    opts = [strategy: :simple_one_for_one, name: SupervisorStop.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end

defmodule SupervisorStop.Worker do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(args) do
    GenServer.start_link(SupervisorStop.Worker, args, [])
  end

  def init(trap_exit) do
    Logger.info "#{inspect self} trap_exit: #{inspect trap_exit}"
    if trap_exit do
      Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    end
    {:ok, []}
  end

  def terminate(reason,_state) do
    Logger.info "terminating: #{inspect self}: #{inspect reason}"
    :ok
  end      
end
```

if I run this in iex here is what happens:

```
09:55:26 alex@alexmac test0 > iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Interactive Elixir (1.3.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Supervisor.start_child(SupervisorStop.Supervisor, [true])

09:59:16.086 [info]  #PID<0.102.0> trap_exit: true
{:ok, #PID<0.102.0>}
iex(2)> Supervisor.start_child(SupervisorStop.Supervisor, [false])
{:ok, #PID<0.104.0>}

09:59:21.113 [info]  #PID<0.104.0> trap_exit: false
iex(3)> Supervisor.stop(SupervisorStop.Supervisor)

09:59:35.702 [info]  terminating: #PID<0.102.0>: :shutdown
:ok
iex(4)>
09:59:35.710 [info]  Application test0 exited: normal

nil
```

as you can see from the output the worker that trapped exits has its terminate callback invoked before it dies hence

09:59:16.086 [info]  #PID<0.102.0> trap_exit: true
   ...
   09:59:35.702 [info]  terminating: #PID<0.102.0>: :shutdown

the other pid is not reporting its terminate called. That is because

09:59:21.113 [info]  #PID<0.104.0> trap_exit: false

There is very useful article if you really want to understand all the different combinations:

http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-01-24-understanding-exit-signals-in-erlang-slash-elixir/

Comment: Well, I ended up running GenServer.stop(child) on all children of supervisor through Task.async and stopping the Supervisor after that. My main goal was to let servers finish whatever they were doing, but prevent receiving more messages. Your experiment proves that children are getting killed brutally when Supervisor stops, just as I suspected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the great article: "Who supervises the supervisors"

> When the top-level supervisor is asked to terminate, it calls exit(ChildPid, shutdown) on each of the Pids. If the child is a worker and trapping exits, it'll call its own terminate function. Otherwise, it's just going to die. When a supervisor gets the shutdown signal, it will forward it to its own children the same way.

In short if you want to gracefully shutdown a worker:

- Make it **trap exits**
- Handle the shutdown in its `terminate` function

Source: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors